# PropertyChangedEventHandler event only handled once

Tags: c#, uwp

I use `OnPropertyChanged("property");` to raise the event via a setter of a property.

Class1.xaml.cs:

```
public Class1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Class2.PropertyChanged += delegate
    {
        // do stuff
    };
}
```

In Class2.cs I have the following:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
public static void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

The delegate in Class1 executes one time. Class2 works as expected. I checked this with breakpoints.

What happens in order is:

> Class2 fires event
>
> Class1 handles event
>
> Class2 fires event
>
> Class2 fires event

Also, when I remove `= delegate { }` the second time the handler is null.

How can I handle the event in Class1 every time it fires in Class2?

EDIT:

My project structure is the following:

**App**

Location of Class1, main project.

**App.Shared**

Location of Class2, shared logic for main and background project.

**App.Background**

Background project for
`IBackgroundTask`. Here I call `OnPropertyChanged("property")`.

Comment: The simple explanation is that you have more than one instance of Class2.  The first one has its event subscribed, the other one(s) don't.  Debug this by adding a constructor, if necessary, and set a breakpoint on it.

Comment: From the information available your code should work. If at some point you are no longer receiving any events, it should be because you have reset the event delegates list. You can check for all the occurrences of the  Class2.PropertyChanged event and ensure that there is no reset (or unregistration of your delegates)

Comment: @HansPassant you were right. I added my project structure. It seems the event is only handled when it is fired in the main project. I thought there could only be one instance of a static class?